# @ and “ keys are swapped in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

My @ and “ keys are swapped in visual studio along. My OS is windows XP and my language settings is set to English(United States). Somehow visual studio still seems to consider English(United Kingdom) as my language instead of picking up the system settings. Any solutions/suggestions would be a great help.

Thanks in advance,
Bharath K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried;

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> International Settings

Answer (score 0):

Aside from `"` and `@` getting interchanged, this also happens to `$` becomes libras, `|` becomes `~`.  I happen to experience it in word, excel and sqldeveloper.

My solution works only if this thing happen without you getting busy with the control panel keyboard setting.  To bring them back to order, try pressing the left <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys at the same time.  Remember, this trick only works if you have not altered anything in the control panel keyboard setting.